# Ant: Loading a build file from a url

Tags: java, svn, ant, jenkins

I have a svn controlled project and i'm trying to use ant in Jenkins. The problem is that the `build.xml` for the project is only reachable by **URL**. How do i make ant load the `build.xml` from the **URL** instead of it looking at the relative path? I've tried adding `/` at the start of the **URL**. That makes it not use the relative path but it also breaks my URL because it doesn't ignore the `/`.

> Error without /:
>
> FATAL: Unable to find build script at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ant Build\http:\???\build.xml
>
> Error with /:
>
> FATAL: Unable to find build script at /http:/???/build.xml

Comment: Isn't your build.xml together with your project in svn? You need to checkout the project (including the build.xml) from svn (there is an option in Jenkins for it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this some time ago, but i've forgotten about this question until now.
What i did was to link to the **local build.xml** in the project directory instead of the **URL**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Hudson 3.1.0.
A workaround that worked for me is to edit the job's config.xml file:

```
<entry>
  <string>customWorkspace</string>
  <string-property>
    <originalValue class="string">## full path of your build.xml file ##</originalValue>
    <propertyOverridden>false</propertyOverridden>
  </string-property>
</entry>
```

The line that begins with originalValue was missing.